# Relationships from EF View to EF Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, sql-view

I have successfully created an EF Core that maps to my view.  How can I added a relationship to the view to my other entity classes?

Here is the the View:

```
public class AppUserClaim
{
    [Key]
    public int ClaimId { get; set; }
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    public string AppUserDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyClaimName { get; set; }
}
```

In my DBContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<AppUserClaim>(appUserClaim =>
            {
                appUserClaim.HasNoKey();
                appUserClaim.ToView("View_AppUserClaims");
            });
    }
```

I would now like to be able to add the relationship to my user class in a way like this but it does not work.

I get this error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'AppUser.AppUserClaims' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

and this is how i tried to add the relationship to my AppUserClass:

```
public ICollection<AppUserClaim> AppUserClaims { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you explain what "add a relationship to the view to my other entity classes" means? I don't understand. Do you want to add the `AppUserClaim` as a relational property to every class?

Comment: From my user class, I want to access the UserClaims collection as shown on the bottom.  The usage would equal:

foreach(AppUserClaim c in appUser.AppUserClaims){
    <td>@c.ClaimType</td>
    <td>@c.ClaimId</td>
}

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think something like this should work.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var table1Entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>();
        table1Entity.ToTable(nameof(Table1));
        table1Entity.HasKey(i => i.Id);
        table1Entity.Property(i => i.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
        var view1Query = modelBuilder.Query<View1>(); // we assume this view already exists in the DB
        view1Query.ToView(nameof(View1));
        view1Query.HasOne(i => i.Table1).WithMany().HasForeignKey(i => i.Table1Id);
    }
```

Where Table1 is the table entity and View1 is the view entity.

This should add a relationship between your table and your view.